# Can custom close reasons make use of magic links like [edit]?

Tags: support, markdown, custom-close-reasons, magic-links

ELL is [writing up a replacement for one of its close reasons](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/lets-rewrite-the-proofreading-close-reason/) and ran into the question of whether it's possible to put a link to each question's own edit page within the reason itself, so we can even more strongly emphasize just how easy it can be to get the question back in action.

Beyond just this particular use case, though, is there general documentation on what magic links work in close reasons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They can make use of magic links *like* [edit], but they can't make use of [edit] - or [main], or [meta].

[chat], [tag:... links, help center links and site links all work properly though.

Comment: Well, that makes me a little sad, but I suppose I can live with that. (There's no need for \[main] or \[meta], but \[edit] would certainly be handy.)

Comment: So, if a question gets closed with that reason and part of the answer includes `[edit]` (without the backticks) it will not convert to a link? Is there any way to do this that can be standardized at all?

Comment: Every single close reason already has a link to the edit page below it...

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that.

Comment: You might want to put the info form your last comment into the answer, since it pretty much solves the specific problem that the question adressed.

Comment: @Shog9: We've observed that a close reason including "edit" specifically (no link) does significantly better in editing and reopening than others, so it seems that even that limited extra push can be surprisingly helpful to get people to do what's needed.