# Textbox placeholder for creating a site-specific close reason includes invalid short links

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, magic-links, custom-close-reasons

When a diamond moderator creates a new site-specific close reason, they are presented with a form to specify the various notices that should appear on closed posts. One of those notices, the one displayed to the post owner, contains short links in its placeholder text that do not work:

[image: Update the question so others can reproduce the problem. You can edit the question or post a new one.]

<s>In retrospect, I am pretty sure the correct syntax for these links is to use square brackets, not parentheses, so the placeholder should read `[edit the question][edit] or [post a new one][ask]`.</s> It turns out these links [don’t work in post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262248). However, I made the mistake of trusting that the placeholder’s syntax was correct, so one of our site-specific close reasons on [PLDI](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/) renders incorrectly:

[image: If possible, consider editing this]

Even diamond moderators cannot edit the text of close reasons once they are active, so the only way to fix this on existing posts would be to escalate to an SE employee, which makes this particularly annoying despite being such an apparently minor issue.

Comment: I don't think the correct format for these as magic links would work as you suggest, though: `[editing][edit]` renders as [editing][edit], `[editing](edit)` renders as [editing](edit). And that's just in comments. The correct format for the `[edit]` and `[ask]` magic links is just to surround the word in brackets; you can't customize the link text when using magic links.

Comment: ...In any case, it looks like the `[edit]` magic link (and some others) doesn't work in post notices. See here for more info: [Can custom close reasons make use of magic links like \[edit\]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262248/335251) That said, as mentioned in the comments there: "Every single close reason already has a link to the edit page below it..."

Comment: (In any case, the placeholder/hint text for these fields should definitely be changed to not suggest something that doesn't actually work. For now, I've removed these non-functional links from PLDI's custom close reasons.)

Comment: Related documentation request: [What Replacement Strings are available for use in Community Specific Close Reasons?](/q/378735/1099857) It'd be generally helpful if there were some documentation somewhere on what does and does not work in community-specific close reasons. (Beyond just fixing the issue within the UI)

Comment: Testing, but I think the problem is that there's a backslash getting removed by the code... [editing](/edit)... yes. So it's really just `[editing](/edit)`... The syntax is ... mostly correct and is not intended to be the variant with two sets of brackets. @V2Blast :) This syntax does work in post notices.

Comment: Anyway, I've updated the close reasons y'all created to use the correct syntax and I'll see what we can do about finding that missing backslash. (both the current and old one)

Comment: @Catija Surely that link does not go anywhere useful? The resolved link would be `https://sitename.stackexchange.com/edit`, which is not a real page (the link you posted above 404s).

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah. :D Apologies. Pretend I didn't say anything :D (I removed the links from the close reasons) - Regarding other links, it should work if you get the full remainder of the URL - such as `[ask a new one](/questions/ask)` ... even for editing it should work it's just that it requires the post ID, which we can't pull.

Comment: @Catija Thanks, and no worries. :)